# react redux not updating view component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, reducers

my view is now updating when redux state is changed, but if i click button "toggleToDoReducer" the view is updating to the new state.
here's my code

```
const toggleToDoReducer = (state, payload) => {
  return ({
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === payload) {
        return { text: item.text, isChecked: !item.isChecked }
      }

      return item
    })
  })
}

shuffleMe = (oldData) => {
  let i, j, temp;
  for (i = oldData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    temp = oldData[i];
    oldData[i] = oldData[j];
    oldData[j] = temp;
  }
  let newArray = oldData;
  return (newArray)
}

const shuffleReducer = (state) => {
  return ({
    ...state,
    items: shuffleMe(state.items)
  })
}
```

any help would be great appreciated

Comment: aside great answer from @nithin, i also found solution for my code above,
simply change "let newArray = oldData;" to "let newArray = oldData.slice();" this will also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think shuffleMe function is mutating the state directly. Rather pass the copy of the state. An sample implementation below

```js
const toggleToDoReducer = (state, payload) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map((item, index) => {
      if (index === payload) {
        return { text: item.text, isChecked: !item.isChecked };
      }

      return item;
    })
  };
};

const shuffleMe = oldData => {   
    oldData.forEach((element, i) => {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [oldData[i], oldData[j]] = [oldData[j], oldData[i]];     
    });
  return oldData;
};

const shuffleReducer = state => {
  return {
    ...state,
    items: shuffleMe([...state.items])
  };
};
```

Comment: code above worked!
and still work even only change "items: shuffleMe(state.items)" to "items: shuffleMe([...state.items])".
thanks, good day

Answer (score 0):

Try with `setState({})` function for re-render your view.